# Why HttpClient of .NET Core /5/6+ doesn't follow a redirection from HTTPS to HTTP even if AllowAutoRedirect is set to true?

Tags: dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?view=net-6.0

> Note:
> With AllowAutoRedirect set to true, the .NET Framework will follow redirections even when being redirected to an HTTP URI from an HTTPS URI. .NET Core versions 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0 will not follow a redirection from HTTPS to HTTP even if AllowAutoRedirect is set to true.

I am a little confused why this by design?

Comment: Because it's from secure (HTTPS) to unsecure (HTTP). If I enter a HTTPS url in my browser,  I also won't expect to end up with HTTP.

Comment: Because going from HTTPS to HTTP is potentially insecure

Comment: @Julian sounds make sense, but some internal SSO website, for example, https://......./target=http://aservice.com, will response 302 to http... I don't know how to deal with that with HttpClient with .net 6

Comment: Or keep everything http, or all https, or read the response and do a manual redirect.

Comment: You could, and here's a thought, get the location response header and manually follow it!